# How to catch data send by postman via form-data to laravel controller

Tags: php, laravel, postman

I can catch data send in JSON format but when I send data by form-data it outputs following

```
{
    "status": "error",
    "status_code": 422,
    "message": "Fields Validation Failed.",
    "data": {
        "email": [
            "The email field is required."
        ],
        "password": [
            "The password field is required."
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the fields in the "body" and the value of the field in the "value".

Comment: i did this Body->form-data->key and value pair

Comment: @AnkitBihani There you go.

Comment: my controller is public function authenticate(Request $request)
    {  
        $rules = array (
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required',
        );
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
        if ($validator-> fails()){
            return $this->respondValidationError('Fields Validation Failed.', $validator->errors());
        }